# Android text input from XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I am struggling to learn how XML layouts in android work.  I suspect my question has been asked before, but I can't find the answer.
I am looking at the APIDemos tutorial that comes with the android SDK.  There is a class called AlertDialogSamples in it.  I am working with the custom DIAGLOG_TEXT_ENTRY case.  I understand how to get the view to be added to the dialog box and how to make the labels and text box change.
I cannot understand how to get the user input text from the boxes and do somethign with it.  In the lines:

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
     }
```

How do I get the user input values of the username and password fields and use them where is says User clicked OK?  They should be EditText objects, but I am unfamiliar with how to access these fields since they are formed using XML instead of writting them in JAVA.  How do I access XML generated objects?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ids on the `EditText` fields in your layout xml:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username"
    ... />
<EditText android:id="@+id/password"
    ... />
```

Then at any time inside your activity you can reference them by:

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

You can get their text by using `username.getText()`, which returns a `CharSequence` and can be used like a `String`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I just tried this, but I get a null pointer exception when I try this. The exception occurs on the getText() line. The getText returns an Editable object. My code is as below:
.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
System.out.println(text.getText().toString());
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }

Comment: Your view isn't being found. Are you sure that you are loading the right layout?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

String string=editText.getText().toString();

if(!string.equals("")){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
System.out.println(string);

}